# Django filter on ordered table memory usage

Tags: django, memory, filter

I have an ordered table defined as following in model.py (Blog is another table):

```
class OrderedBlog(Blog):
  class Meta:
    ordering = ["-time_created"]
    proxy = True
```

If I try to do something like:

```
OrderedBlog.objects.filter(time_created__lt = a_specific_time)
```

Would this bring all entries of Blog in memory? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wont. When you are going to iterate over the the queryset, then Django will start loading each element of the queryset into memory and instantiate it one at a time.

If you are concerned about memory usage you'd better go for [Queryset.iterator()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) or retrieve only the fields you are interested in using [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only).